# Perl/Bash Solution to Test if a Folder Has Changed, Then Create Copy of It

Tags: bash, backup, rsync, perl

I'd like to put together a script for a very rudimentary backup system that checks a directory recursively for any changes since the date another directory (the backup) was created and, if it finds changes, it creates another backup that is sequentially incremented from the previous backup.

To put it another way, I'm looking for the equivalent of if I could just ask rsync, "Is there anything you would synchronize if I ran you right now?" If the result were "true"/"yes" then instead of synchronizing the directory, I could test that result and simply copy the entire directory to a new folder.

Imagine this pseudo code:

```
$directoryModDate = [command to find date of most recently modified in directory or subdirectories thereof];
$mostRecentBackupDate = [command to find date most recent backup folder was created, e.g. backup1, backup2, backup3...];

if ($directoryModDate > $mostRecentBackupDate) {
     copy "/path/to/source", $backupDestination;
     say STDOUT "New backup folder created.";
}
else {
     say STDOUT "Previous backup is current."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the
 `-n, --dry-run`
options for rsync, this might be a route to create the answer for you.

Note though that
`$ rsync -avP source dest`
might well be able to replace your script entirely.